# git : how to merge a file from another repo (with different file path)?

Tags: git

I created a NEW_REPO. Same code as OLD_REPO but with different arborescence.

I need to merge
`old/path/to/my_file.txt` from the `OLD_REPO` (`my_branch`) into

`newly/added/folder/old/path/to/my_file.txt` of the `NEW_REPO` (`my_branch`)

What I've done (from the NEW_REPO) :

```
git remote add OLD_REPO https://...
git fetch OLD_REPO <commit-sha> 
git co -b my_branch
```

and then

```
git checkout <commit-sha> -- my_file.txt

error: pathspec 'my_file.txt' did not match any file(s) known to git
```

I guess I need to find a way to indicate the path to my_file but I don't know how to do it, hence this question.

So : How to merge a file from another repo, with different file path ?

Thanks !

Comment: You need to specify the path to the file as it is in `<commit-sha>`, to the best of my knowledge.... but that won't _merge_ the file, just in case. It will put it in your working tree/index as it is in the other branch. Could also try with `git restore --worktree --source=commit-sha -- ./my-file.txt` but it needs to be full path as it is on that commit.

Comment: I'm trying `git checkout -p <commit-sha> -- old/path/to/my_file.txt` but I don't know how to tell git to merge this old file to the `new/path/to/my_file.txt`.

Comment: That's the thing.... it is not being _merged_.